# Is there a way I can turn a string into a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

I'm a bit new to JavaScript so I want to know how I can convert something like this :

```
var names = "{ guy:'Henry' guy2:'Joe' guy3:'Bob' }"
```

from a string into an actual object and then access the values of keys.
I tried to use :

```
names = eval(names)
console.log(names.guy)
```

I'd get undefined
and if i try :

```
console.log(names)
```

I'd get just the first value of the object which is 'Henry'
Please can someone help me with this and if my question wasn't explanatory enough, i can make it clearer

Comment: have you looked into JSON parsing?

Comment: @woozyking The string isn't valid JSON. It's valid JavaScript code.

Comment: @ThomasSablik i see. then it depends on whether this pattern is consistent, a string parsing approach may be viable

Comment: Actually this is not valid JS. Try `eval("(" + names + ")")` ... Also are there commas in it?

Comment: Try this JSON.parse('{"guy":"Henry","guy2":"Joe","guy3":"Bob"}')

Comment: Re "something like this": if you have any choice don't use a made up string format. Instead use string text written in [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/JSON),which is a standardized way of serializing object data. If someone is forcing their made up format on you, tell them to use JSON.

Comment: This is a non standard format. It's nearly impossible to write a reliable parser without specification just with one example. You should either use a standard format like JSON or specify the format. Does your format support numbers, nested objects, spaces or arrays?

Answer (score 0):

with quite a bit of assumptions, the foremost being the given string has a fixed pattern as in OP, then something like this *may* fit the need:

```
var names = "{ guy:'Henry' guy2:'Joe' guy3:'Bob' }"


names = names
  .replace(/^{/, '') // remove leading '{'
  .replace(/}$/, '') // reomve closing '}'
  .trim() // trim surrounding empty spaces
  .split(' ') // split out key:value pairs
  .map((s) => s.split(':')) // "parse" supposed key:value pairs
  .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
    acc[k] = eval(v) // suppose the value portion is always quoted
    return acc
  }, {})

console.log(names.guy)
```

but if you have the choice of the input, rather ensure that it comes in as a valid JSON string, as suggested in the comments section

Answer (score -1):

As you mentiond your variable is a string which you can parse into an object by using `let v = JSON.parse(names)`. You can than use `console.log(names.guy)` to output the value. If you wanted to cast an object to a string you could use `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: `"{ guy:'Henry' guy2:'Joe' guy3:'Bob' }"` is neither valid JSON nor valid JavaScript.